# exclude posts without content from search result

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I have search.php in my WordPress theme, search result is generating fine using The Loop.

What I see is some post don't have content(blank post with title only), and they still appear in search result. Which is quite obvious, but I want only to list post which has some content.

If post don't have any content it should not list in Search Result even if its title has a Search Term.

I believe you won't need to see code to understand my concern. I tried searching for this answer on all known resources, nothing found exactly.

Down vote won't help me.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your search loop try adding this:

```
global $post;
if ( $post->post_content != '' ) {
    // Display this post because it has content.
} else {
    // This post has empty content so do not display it.
}
```